# Can not read data correctly from Pandas read_csv

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame:

```
from pandas import read_excel, read_csv, merge
df1 = read_csv('some.csv').T
```

```
csv= (column, xyz, yzx
      a, 13,  12
      b, 154, 15
      c, 213, 16
      n, 1231,1230)
```

I get a dataframe.

```
df1 =          0    1    2 .......  n

     column    a    b    c .......  n
     xyz      13   154  213        1231
     yzx      12   15   16         1230
```

When I check  `df1 .columns` columns I get   `RangeIndex(start=0, stop=56202, step=1)`

I wish to get `['column, a, b, c.....n]`. If I try `df1 = read_csv('some.csv', index_col = 0).T`

I get

```
Index(['a', 'b', 'c',...'n'], dtype='object', name='column', length=193921)
```

What is the function of the "name" = How do I set that column as an index? I don't really understand setting indices. tried with `reset_index`, `set_index`....

It's important because I use this column to merge in the future.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The question would be clearer if you posted a few lines from your original csv as well as your desired `df1` output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this sample csv:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
csv = StringIO('''
column,xyz,yzx
a,13,12
b,154,15
c,213,16
n,1231,1230
''')
```

I think this is what you're after:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(csv).set_index('column').T
df = df.rename_axis('column').reset_index()
df.columns.name = None

#    column  a   b    c    n
# 0  xyz     13  154  213  1231
# 1  yzx     12  15   16   1230
```

```py
df.columns

# Index(['column', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'n'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: No that returns Index(['a', 'b', 'c',...'n'], dtype='object', name='column', length=193921) this output. I wish to have 'column" in the list. like Index(['column', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])....

Comment: Ok I think I see what you're wanting now. I updated my answer.

Comment: You, sir/mam, are awesome :)